# Finding angles between two images opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I have an image, then I turn it around three axes with warpPerspective(). I have two images then, so I want to find transformation which will translate the first picture to the second and get rotation and translation vectors.

I know it can be done with homography matrix

[image: Perspective correction]

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html, It worked when I rotated the picture in its plane(i found keypoints using ORB). Now I change 3 angles, and  get homography matrix, which seems to be incorrect. I can decompose it in two ways, and both of them can't calculate 2 other angles.

[image: Source picture]
[image: Second image]
The angles I rotated the first photo to get the second one are: 20, 30, 45. Both of methods say that angles are 0,0,~50.

Comment: Do you expect to measure the angle change of the object or of the camera?

Comment: Could you explain what the difference is. My global task is to glue photos of the area when flying a drone with a camera, I have all needed data from the camera: the internal matrix and distortion coefficients, but I think  i need only do homography here, am I wrong?